# Any Group By and Aggregate function per table in range queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for aggregate function (sum/avg) per table from the below like query.

SELECT
  sum(qty)
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([black-resource-174911:owner],'table_id CONTAINS "sales2017"')
where category='shoes'

I am expecting:

### sum  table

100 sales2017W1
200 sales2017W2
250 sales2017W3

Is there any such option in BigQuery? Appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(qty) AS sum, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table 
FROM `black-resource-174911.owner.sales2017*`
WHERE category = 'shoes'
GROUP BY table
```